# Instead of FirstOrDefault() what do I use to get all values in group by?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

How can I get all the values of SpecificationDetails_ID.By the below code I just get the first value  form a group of values.What to do to get all values?

```
using(APM context=new APM())
{
      var  lstprodspc = (from s in context.M_ProductSpecifaction
    //join p in context.M_SpecificationDetails on s.SpecificationDetails_ID equals p.ID
    // join r in context.M_Specifications on p.Specification_ID equals r.ID
                          where s.Product_ID == P_ID
                          group s by s.Parent_ID into pg
                          select new 
                          {
                              ProductSD_ID = pg.FirstOrDefault().SpecificationDetails_ID 
                          }).ToList();
}
```

[image: Here attaching the image of table values :]

[image]

From the above code I just get 34,31,31,31,26,26,26,26.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can project it using `Select` like this:-

```
 select new 
        {
           Parent_ID = pg.Key,
           ProductSD_ID = pg.Select(x => x.SpecificationDetails_ID).ToList()
        }).ToList();
```